# Fatal error Call to a member function isLogged() on in OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart, fatal-error, opencart2.x

After migrating my website from one hosting server to another I am getting the following error in my admin page, which does not open.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function isLogged() on null in
>   /webcorp1/www/corpusers/s/a/satvikorganic.com/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_model_catalog_product.php
>   on line 96

Comment: Have you tried clearing the vqmod cache?

Comment: Is everything fine with all frontend pages?

Comment: Yes ,i already clear cache through "$vqmod->useCache = true;"... But still its showing the same..

Comment: Sankar V-- Yes ,Frontend pages all are working fine.When am going to admin this error is showing

Answer (score 3):

Have been working on an opencart site and have had the same issue, turns out I had naively copied the same paths from my front end config file into the admin config.php file. The following variables need to have the admin folder specified and cant be the same as the front end paths:

define('DIR_APPLICATION', '**YOURPATH**/admin/');

define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '**YOURPATH**/admin/language/');

define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '**YOURPATH**/admin/view/template/');

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that both config files (admin and root) are updated with the server path
2. Rerun your vQmod install script http://domain.com/vqmod/install/
3. Clear vQmod cache
4. Clear Opencart system cache