# Opencart .. admin 500 error

Tags: php, opencart

Woke up this morning not being able to access my admin in opencart. Login would not allow. Edited something and now I have a 500 error on admin.

> [Sun Nov 27 08:26:58.521365 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 11194] [client
>   86.161.65.106:51914] AH01215: PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function isLogged() on null in
>   /home/xxxxx/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_model_catalog_product.php
>   on line 468: /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php56

Tried deleting entire contents of vqcache. Didn't work. Checked config files for public and admin both seem to be correct.

HELP!

Comment: Do the `catalog/controller/user/user.php` and `system/library/user.php`
files exist in your system ?

Comment: Yep. Nothing in that respect has ever been touched. I changed a URL in config.. it messed up into a 500 error. I put it back. Still error

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628307/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-islogged-on-in-opencart

Comment: Tried this. Checked permissions on files. Correct. Checked ownership. Correct. Still no luck.